# Search duplicates using values from other table as keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I guess that the title doesn't explain the question well but lets see an example, I have the following tables:

```
orders table:
order_id
9
10
11
12

order_details table:
order_id, product_id  
9,        7
9,        8
10,       5
10,       6
11,       6
11,       7
12,       8
12,       9

products table:
product_id, product_name, price, ext_id  
5,          poteto,       4.99,  null
6,          potato,       7.5,   55
7,          orange,       7.99,  77
8,          green apple,  5.99,  88
9,          gren-aple,    6.99,  null

products_old table:
product_id, key,              value
5,          product name,     poteto
5,          price,            4.99
5,          external id,      55      
9,          product name,     gren-aple
9,          price,            6.99
9,          external id,      88
```

I want to find orders with duplicated products (only different product_id but same external_id) if products name would be identical it will be easy using the following query:

```
select od.order_id
from order_details od join
     products p
     on od.product_id = p.product_id
group by od.order_id
having count(p.product_name) > count(distinct p.product_name)
```

But how to handle it when the names are different (for example some spelling mistakes etc.) but I have additional table where external_id (which is the same for same products, eg. green apple and gren-aple) is stored as showen above?
Note that only duplicates that have null ext_id are in table products_old.
I'd be very grateful for help :)!

Comment: consider keeping unique `product_id` for each `product_name` in a look-up(master) table, such as `1-potato  2-orange 3-green apple .....`. And Do not hold `product_name`s as string in the child table, instead hold them  as integer reference values which are derived from the look-up table.

Comment: I need to resolve this without changes in tables structure

Comment: Design issues turn back as headaches in the future, better to fix at the start :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with idea to extract a list of external_id from the table but I'm stuck now to check if both from products and products_old are in the order.

```
externalIDs AS (select CAST (value as INT) from products_old where key = 'external_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the external ids are different from the internal ids, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
having count(coalesce(p.ext_id, p.product_id)) > count(distinct coalesce(p.ext_id, p.product_id))
```

In your case, you can construct the values as well:

```
having count(coalesce('EXT:' || p.ext_id::text, 'INT:' || p.product_id)) >
       count(distinct coalesce('EXT:' || p.ext_id::text, 'INT:' || p.product_id))
```

Comment: Somehow it doesn't work for me, I managed to generate products_old table in more 'friendly' way that is I think easier to operate later: 
oldproducts AS (select product_id, CAST(value as INT) AS external_id from products_old where key = 'external_id')

But I'm still stuck, tried few queries but came out they are pointless.